# PackageManager getChangedPackages always return NULL

Tags: android

In my app I need to monitorize recently added or updated packages, but since Oreo this is a hard task.

To do it I have a service that runs every X time to detect the new installed/updated apps.

The main core of this service is to call the getChangedPackages function from the PackageManager, but this function always returns null, even if I install or update any app from or not from the Play Store in the interval between two consequtive calls to getChangedPackages.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getChangedPackages(int)

I need to request any permission to call this function? Is the getChangedPackages buggy?

```
    private void _doProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            PackageManager package_manager = getPackageManager();
            int sequence_number = ApplicationPreferences.getInteger(this, GET_CHANGED_PACKAGES_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_KEY, 0);
            ChangedPackages changed_packages = package_manager.getChangedPackages(sequence_number);
            LogUtilities.show(this, String.format("Retrieve recently apps installs/updates using sequence number %d returns %s", sequence_number, changed_packages == null ? "null" : "a not null object"));
            if (changed_packages == null) changed_packages = package_manager.getChangedPackages(0);
LogUtilities.show(this, String.format("Retrieve recently apps installs/updates using sequence number %d returns %s", sequence_number, changed_packages == null ? "null" : "a not null object"));
            if (changed_packages != null)
            {
                List<String> packages_names = changed_packages.getPackageNames();
                LogUtilities.show(this, String.format("%d recently installed/updated apps", packages_names == null ? 0 : packages_names.size()));
                if (packages_names != null) for (String package_name : packages_names) PackagesUpdatedReceiver.doProcessPackageUpdate(this, new Intent(isNewInstall(package_manager, package_name) ? Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED : Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", package_name))));
                LogUtilities.show(this, String.format("Storing %s is the sequence number for next iteration", changed_packages.getSequenceNumber()));
                ApplicationPreferences.putInteger(this, GET_CHANGED_PACKAGES_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_KEY, changed_packages.getSequenceNumber());
            }
            else
            {
                LogUtilities.show(this, String.format("Storing %s is the sequence number for next iteration", sequence_number + 1));
                ApplicationPreferences.putInteger(this, GET_CHANGED_PACKAGES_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_KEY, sequence_number + 1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogUtilities.show(this, e);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: I didn't run into any problems when I tested it last. Are you getting new sequence numbers?

Comment: Execution of "ChangedPackages changed_packages = package_manager.getChangedPackages(sequence_number)" is always assigning "null" to changed_packages :(

Comment: It needs to be executed outside the main thread?

Comment: With regards to `null`, are you getting that even for a sequence number of `0`? In my case, I happen to call `getChangedPackages()` on a background thread, though I don't know that it is required. There is no permission for it.

Comment: Well, is done! I have restarted the sequence_number to 0 and is working fine, now. Thanks

Comment: I have tried the "getChangedPackaes" sometimes and in some cases is returning packages that aren't recently installed/updated or removed. :(

Comment: I run a test app that calls getChangedPackages() periodically on an Android Oreo device while not changing any package. The sequence number is incremented after each call. So the return value should be null. However, it is not null in most cases. Instead, it contains most of the packages that are installed on the device. So I’m also wondering how reliable this API is. An alternative method would be to compare the installed packages between 2 consecutive calls so as to get a list of added and removed packages in-between. But this may exclude the updated ones. Any better method?

Comment: I find this API unreliable too. I don't get the delta package changes if i call it from an alarm manager receiver.

Answer (score 1):

My experimental results so far have shown that this PackageManager API method getChangedPackages() is not reliable: quite often the returned ChangedPackages value contains many unchanged packages. So I’ve decided to implement a similar feature in a class called PackageUtils, as shown below. The idea is to poll for all the installed packages, as shown in method getInstalledPackageNames() below, and compare the string list with a previously saved one. This comparison boils down to comparing 2 string lists, as shown in method operate2StringLists() below. To get a set of removed packages, use GET_1_MINUS_2_OR_REMOVED as operation. To get a set of added packages, use GET_2_MINUS_1_OR_ADDED as operation.

```
public class PackageUtils {
    public static final int GET_1_MINUS_2_OR_REMOVED = 0;
    public static final int GET_2_MINUS_1_OR_ADDED   = 1;

    // Get all the installed package names
    public static List<String> getInstalledPackageNames(Context context) {
        List<String> installedPackageNames = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : appInfoList) {
                installedPackageNames.add(appInfo.packageName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return installedPackageNames;
    }

    // Compare 2 string lists and return differences.
    public static Set<String> operate2StringLists(List<String> pkgList1, List<String> pkgList2, int operation) {
        Set<String> result = null;
        Set<String> pkgSet1 = new HashSet<String>(pkgList1);
        Set<String> pkgSet2 = new HashSet<String>(pkgList2);

        switch (operation) {
            case GET_1_MINUS_2_OR_REMOVED:
                pkgSet1.removeAll(pkgSet2);
                result = pkgSet1;
                break;
            case GET_2_MINUS_1_OR_ADDED:
                pkgSet2.removeAll(pkgSet1);
                result = pkgSet2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The code has been tested on an Android Oreo device. It can reliably detect all added and removed packages between 2 time instances. However, it can’t detect updated packages in-between.

Comment: How are you saving the lists?

Comment: getInstalledPackageNames() returns List<String>; operate2StringLists() returns Set<String>. You can save the return values as-is, or you can convert between List<> and Set<> if you prefer one to the other. Does this answer your question @Satish Shetty?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. You have to create a variable called `sequenceNumber`, and update it every time you query changed packages.

```
private static int sequenceNumber = 0;
...
PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
ChangedPackages changedPackages = pm.getChangedPackages(sequenceNumber);
if(changedPackages != null)
    sequenceNumber = changedPackages.getSequenceNumber();
```